# Hodge dual and the Moyal bracket? Any link?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, phase-space, poisson-brackets

I have already asked this on the mathematics Stack exchange but I thought I'd try it here too!

The [Hodge star operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual) $\star$ is a linear map between $\bigwedge ^pV$ and $\bigwedge ^{n-p}V$ for an inner product space $V$ of dimension $n$. 
So we can we write;
\begin{equation}
\lambda\in \bigwedge ^p V
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\star\lambda\in\bigwedge^{n-p}V
\end{equation}

1. I am wondering is this the same operation as used in the [Moyal bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_bracket) for functions in phase space?

Namely for two functions of the phase space $f$ and $g$, the Moyal bracket is given by;
\begin{equation}
\{f,g\}:=\frac{1}{i\hbar}(f\star g-g\star f).
\end{equation}
I think I'm wrong and that it is somehow a different operation with the same sign, but would really appreciate some help since I'm really not familiar with the Hodge operator other than what I have written above!

2. Also if its not too much trouble, could anyone provide a bit of context to the Hodge star operation in physics? e.g. why should I really be interested in vectors in $\bigwedge ^{n-p}V$ space?

Comment: Moyal product is a product on a certain space of functions, while the Hodge operator is a map between exterior forms

Comment: Why should it be the same operation? They act on totally different spaces! Also, the exterior product arises naturally in the course of looking at [differential forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).

Comment: I just wondered if the Moyal bracket was some form of "natural relation" between functions on phase space, just like we have these natural mappings between $\bigwedge^p V$ and $\bigwedge ^{n-p}V$.

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1095512/11127

Comment: Maybe category theory has something to say about this? Also, I don't think this is a question suited to this site: It belongs on [math.se]!